# MySQL string split

Tags: sql, mysql, string

I uploaded a csv file to MySQL DB but for some reason data from two columns got glued to one.

e.g. the data 0880174V,D should have gone to two different columns.

Is there a way (via sql) i can split the data from this column (i.e. as 0880174V and D) and update the table, without having to delete the record and re-upload? I have a million records.

==CURRENT

```
Column A       Column B
0880174V,D
```

== EXPECTED

```
Column A       Column B
0880174V        D
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET ColumnB = SUBSTRING(ColumnA, INSTR(ColumnA, ',') + 1),
    ColumnA = SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 1, INSTR(ColumnA, ',') - 1)
```

Do a `SELECT TOP` first to ease your mind.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although it kind of did the reverse (D   0880174V) instead of (0880174V  D), i got the insight. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Yap, you are right. Sorry, my bad. Changed the answer in any case. Is late in my time zone, if that is to any aval :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify field terminator

```
load data local infile 'file.csv' into myTable
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(col1,col2)
```

**EDIT**: nvm

Answer (score 1):

a simpler solution is to use SUBSTRING_INDEX instead of SUBSTRING with INSTR

UPDATE my_table
SET ColumnB = SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnA, ',' , 1),
    ColumnA = SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnA, ',' , - 1)